# only print a variable once page is loaded

Tags: php, variables, loops, count, while-loop

I'm looking for a simple way using php and javascript, to print a php variable at the top of the page, and only once the page has loaded and run through a while loop.

Basically, I have a while loop that goes through my database, and prints out a row in a table with a users details.
Each time it finds a user, it adds 1 to a variable that is declared at the beginning of the page.

This is my basic way of counting how many users have been found after a search.

I then print out the variable to inform me.
The only issue, is that I can only print the variable after the loop has fiished, meaning it has to be at the bottom of my page and underneath the table. This is stupid, as I then have to scroll to the bottom of a long table to find the number.

Is there A way that once the loop has finished, and set the count as a variable, I can then have a script go back and print the variable above the table?

Many thanks for any advice you guys can offer.

Cheers, Eds

EDIT: added code example:

```
<?php
$count = '0';
//Print all users with similar names
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
//Start the form for each user to enable editing, along with row onhover colour
echo "<form method='post' action='editor.php'>
    <tr class='tablehover'>";
//Depending on searchby, change which column is bold. Helps pick out users
if($searchby == 'username') {
    echo "<td><div class='userhighlight'>".$row['Username']."</div></td>";
}
else {
    echo "<td>".$row['Username']."</td>";
}
if($searchby == 'firstname') {
    echo "<td><div class='userhighlight'>".$row['First Name']."</div></td>";
}
else {
    echo "<td>".$row['First Name']."</td>";
}
if($searchby == 'lastname') {
    echo "<td><div class='userhighlight'>".$row['Last Name']."</div></td>";
}
else {
    echo "<td>".$row['Last Name']."</td>";
}
if($searchby == 'office') {
    echo "<td><div class='userhighlight'>".$row['Office']."</div></td>";
}
else {
    echo "<td>".$row['Office']."</td>";
}
if($searchby == 'lastlogin') {
    echo "<td><div class='userhighlight'>".$row['Last_Login']."</div></td>";
}
else {
    echo "<td>".$row['Last_Login']."</td>";
}

//Set ID of found user
$id = $row['User ID'];
//Create query to load user roles
$roleqry = "SELECT * FROM `site roles` WHERE `User ID`='$id'";
$roleresult = mysql_query($roleqry);
//Set $roles to gather roles
while($roles = mysql_fetch_assoc($roleresult)) {

//Echo out the rest of the user details into the table
echo "<td>".$roles['Admin']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$roles['Create User']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$roles['Edit User']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$roles['SandS']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$roles['SandS Admin']."</td>";
//Echo the hidden ID field, for editing, along with the edit button
}
echo "<td><input type='text' name='id' size='1' value='".$row['User ID']."' readonly style='visibility:hidden;width:1px;'>
            <input type='submit' value='Edit'></td></tr></form>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='11'><hr /></td></tr>";
$count = $count + 1;
}
?>
```

This obviously ends the loop. But I now have no choice, but to echo the set variable $count after this, putting it at the bottom of the page:

```
echo "<br />".$count." user's found";
```

Comment: On a side note: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply count the number of rows in the result set using `mysql_num_rows()` right?
Then you could set the count before the table begins:

```
Count: <?php echo mysql_num_rows($result) ?>
<table>...</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For the immediate solution, I will do this, as it doesnt involve too much reqriting of my current page.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing the table rows while you loop, you could concatenate them to a variable and print it later.

Like this:

```
$output = '';
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $i++;
    $output .= ....
}

echo $i;
echo $output;
```

But if you're going to print out all rows you should use mysql_num_rows() instead of counting them this way.

Comment: Thanks, several others have suggested I concatenate into variables. I will probably start doing this in future, but for the time being I will simply print the mysql_num_rows function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lots of possibilities here, this is quick and dirty

```
<html>...<body>
Rows found: <span id="rowcount">still calculating</span>
<table>
....
</table>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.getElementById('rowcount').innerHTML='<?php echo $rowcount; ?>';
</script>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it definately fits the bill. I have decided to simply use the mysql_num_rows() function to count the rows and print before showing the table

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not very clear, but you can create the table inside a variable and then print the incremental first:

```
$i=0;
$table = '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $table .= '<tr><td>'.htmlentities($row['field']).'</td></tr>';
  $i++;
}
$table .= '</table>';

echo $i;
echo $table;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, several other people have suggested that I store the table in a variable, and then print it all out at the end. I will probably look into doing this in the future

Answer (score 0):

I'd go the way to separate the logic from the presentation of the page. 
So you should first collect all data you need and then do the presentation.

A templating system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/what.is.smarty.tpl) can be helpful for this. Tough for a quick fix it should be enough to just store the table inside a variable and then print it after you finished loading all the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, several others have proposed I work in this way, so will probably be something I look at doing!